# How to assign default value to const?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a React Native app.

I want to be able to call the `useAppTracking` function with an id if `id` exists, and pass in an empty object if `id` doesn't exist. When attempting to assign a default value to `id`, I hit an error because I am reassigning a `const`. Can someone show me a best-practices way to accomplish what I need, please?

```
  const { id } = route.params;
  ...
  useAppTracking('Goal', id || {});
```

Comment: provide the full context of your code

Comment: `const { id = {} } = route.params` [Destructuring with default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2)